# How to remove some fields from the filter

Tags: magento2, filter

I have all my attribute fields in the filter selection.
I would like to have only a few fields in the filter selection.

How can I remove all my unneeded fields ?

Thanks,

Noemi.

Comment: what version of Magento?

Answer (score 0):

> Admin > Stores > Attributes > Product > Select your attribute >
>   Storefront Properties > Use in Layered Navigation > You set your
>   choice